# NoReverseMatch happens in any Exception

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using django-framework.
There is a question that whatever exception happens in program,it will invoke NoReverseMatch(for example, I put "a = 1/ 0 " in my view code).

Following is my Traceback:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 66, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 146, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 81, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 37, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 87, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 122, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 91, in technical_500_response
    text = reporter.get_traceback_text()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 341, in get_traceback_text
    return t.render(c)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 175, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 943, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 211, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 993, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 703, in resolve
    new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/defaultfilters.py", line 229, in stringformat
    return ("%" + str(arg)) % value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 79, in __repr__
    return repr(self.__cast())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 124, in __cast
    return self.__text_cast()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 112, in __text_cast
    return func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 86, in reverse
    raise NoReverseMatch("%s is not a registered namespace" % key)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'promotions' is not a registered namespace
[2018-08-27 11:37:56,758] [ERROR] "POST /v1/voucher/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

Notes:the traceback will print serval times,and the true error will be print between them.

Follwing is my urls.config

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('address', AddressViewset, base_name="address")
router.register('category', CategoryViewset, base_name='Category')
router.register('product', ProductViewset, base_name='product')
router.register('history', UserProductViewset, base_name='browsehistory')
router.register('order', OrderViewset, base_name='order')
router.register('voucher', VoucherViewset, base_name='voucher')

urlpatterns = [

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('v1/', include(router.urls)),
    url('v1/login/', include('login.urls')),

]
```

Follow is my INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.flatpages',
'rest_framework',
'rest_framework.authtoken',
'django_filters',
'compressor',
'widget_tweaks',
'login.apps.LoginConfig',
] + get_core_apps(['catalogue', 'address', 'voucher', 'order', 'analytics', 
'offer', 'wishlists', 'dashboard'])
```

get_core_apps is a django-oscar funtion.

I keep dig in and use pdb in django/urls/base.py  line 75, where is the error begin.

Follwing is the code snippet:

```
    import pdb
    pdb.set_trace()
    extra, resolver = resolver.namespace_dict[ns]
    resolved_path.append(ns)
    ns_pattern = ns_pattern + extra
    ns_converters.update(resolver.pattern.converters)
```

And I print some variable

- ns:  'promotions'
- resolver.namespace_dict:{'admin': ('admin\/',  (admin:admin) 'admin/'>)}

To sum up, when error happens, django want to find view function for url "home:promotions", but it can't, and I had checked all places "home:promotions" occurs(which shows in django-oscar code but not mine),the program also didn't touch them.I think the most important thing is find out which line invoke the reverse() for "home:prmotions",how to debug this.

Comment: post the template or the module where you are trying to reverse the url with namespace `promotions` or basically any url that you are trying to reverse.

Comment: Have you included these urls in your main urls module with the namespace `promotions`?

Comment: I didn't involve 'promtion' in my code.

Comment: Post relevant code from your views.

Comment: I think it's not about a specific view function.If there's no error ,the program will run fine.However, if  any exception or error occurs, it will trigger the " promotion"  exception, I just put a code line " a = 1/ 0 "  in my view function,or put other exception, it's the same.

Comment: I think I may ignore some important url config,and then django can't find my url.......

Comment: There is not much data provided to even begin with debugging this.

Comment: It seems that when Django tries to render its 500 error response, it attempts to build a response page that involves reversing a URL with a namespace of "promotions". I would start by doing a recursive grep in your codebase for the word "promotions". It must be in there somewhere.

Comment: hi,@ Will Keeling, I have edit my question, i did some research but also can't find the reason.The promotions app is in django-oscar itself, i didn't touch it in my peoject, it shows in my installed_app and mindware in my project/setting.py. I tried to comment them, but not help.

Answer (score 1):

I find reason.
First I put pdb in url/base.py, and I get the error view's name is "promotion:home".Then I search it in all my project and django-oscar, It is resigned to global variable:

```
OSCAR_HOMEPAGE = reverse_lazy('promotions:home')
```

When i comment this, the error diasppear